# ReactJS - Unexpected token when declaring a variable in component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
export default class CheckOut extends React.Component {

  state = {
    checked: false,
  };

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  var list = [];
```

I'm getting the following error on line `var list = [];`

> unexpected token

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: did you send everything? because I can't see the closing bracket for the class

Comment: Well, you cannot declare a `var` within a `class`. What are you trying to do, where do you expect the array to end up?

Comment: yeah dw resolved now. thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` isn't a valid keyword in that context. You don't need `var` to define instance variables, just `list = []` will suffice in this context. (see how `state` is written?)

```
export default class CheckOut extends React.Component {
   state = {
    checked: false,
  };
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };
  list = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the code as below remove var and it will work. To access list you will write this.list

```
  export default class CheckOut extends React.Component {
       state = {
        checked: false,
      };
     static navigationOptions = {
       header: null,
         };
     list = [];
```